# function tf.slice_input_producer error using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using the tfrecord to deal with sequences dataset. When one example is readed into the memory, I'll get two context features and one sequence feature. The context features are the length of the sequences and the label of the sequences. The sequence feature is a list of bytes with represent the feature of every time step.
So I have three tensor for every example:

```
length  TensorShape([])
label   TensorShape([])
frames  TensorShape([Dimension(None)])
```

I want to use every sequence feature to predict the label, so I have to make the label be the same length as the frame.

```
length=tf.expand_dims(length, 0, name='expand_length')
label=tf.expand_dims(label, 0, name='expand_label')
labels=tf.tile(label, length, name='multi_label')
```

This time I get the following res:

```
labels   TensorShape([Dimension(None)])
frames   TensorShape([Dimension(None)])
```

And I have to push them into a queue so that I can get one single frame and label.

```
frame, label=tf.train.slice_input_producer([frames, labels])
```

Ant then batch them then do the net training routine.

```
frames, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([frame, label], 4, 16, 8)
```

It should work, however, error happened in function tf.train.slice_input_producer Here's the error info:

```
W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow_gpu-r0.12\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:975] Invalid argument: indices = 119 is not in [0, 117)
         [[Node: slice_timestep/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_STRING, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](parse_one_ex/parse_one_ex:2, slice_timestep/fraction_of_32_full_Dequeue)]]
W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow_gpu-r0.12\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:975] Invalid argument: indices = 119 is not in [0, 117)
         [[Node: slice_timestep/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_STRING, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](parse_one_ex/parse_one_ex:2, slice_timestep/fraction_of_32_full_Dequeue)]]
I d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow_gpu-r0.12\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cupti64_80.dll locally
W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow_gpu-r0.12\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:975] Out of range: RandomShuffleQueue '_3_batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 4, current size 0)
         [[Node: batch_ex = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue, batch_ex/n)]]
W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow_gpu-r0.12\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:975] Out of range: RandomShuffleQueue '_3_batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 4, current size 0)
         [[Node: batch_ex = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue, batch_ex/n)]]
W d:\build\tensorflow\tensorflow_gpu-r0.12\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:975] Out of range: RandomShuffleQueue '_3_batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 4, current size 0)
         [[Node: batch_ex = QueueDequeueMany[_class=["loc:@batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue"], component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue, batch_ex/n)]]
```

the name of the slice_input_producer is slice_timestep

the name of the shuffle_batch is batch_ex

Here's the graph showed in my tensorboard.

[the whole graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DANSy.png)

[local zoomed graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4NJw.png)

Below is the simplified code which reproduce the error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

context_features = {
    "length": tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
    "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)
}
sequence_features = {
    "imgs_list": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
}


file=tf.train.string_input_producer(['./train.tfrecord'])
reader=tf.TFRecordReader()
_, ex=reader.read(file)

context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
    serialized=ex,
    context_features=context_features,
    sequence_features=sequence_features
)
length=tf.cast(context_parsed['length'], tf.int32)
label=tf.cast(context_parsed['label'], tf.int32)
length=tf.expand_dims(length, 0, name='expand_length')
label=tf.expand_dims(label, 0, name='expand_label')
label=tf.tile(label, length)
imcontent, label=tf.train.slice_input_producer([sequence_parsed['imgs_list'], label])
im=tf.image.decode_jpeg(imcontent, 3)
im=tf.image.resize_images(im, [224, 224])
im, label = tf.train.shuffle_batch([im, label], 4, 16, 8, name='batch_ex')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
    fig=plt.figure()
    while(True):
        [res, res2]=sess.run([im, label])
        print(res2)
```

Comment: your errors state '_3_batch_ex/random_shuffle_queue is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 4, current size 0)' In my experience that's usually just the indication that it can't read anything out of your input file. Are you sure it's finding it correctly and there is enough stuff in there? It says it's trying to read a set of 4 records and getting zero...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved. It seems that the slice_input_producer is static. I use